# Compose TextField Modifier.onFocusChanged {} event being called upon initialization even though no user focus interactions have been done

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield

Reproducible with code:

```
var value by remember { mutableStateOf("Hello\nWorld\nInvisible") }

TextField(
    value = value,
    onValueChange = { value = it },
    label = { Text("Enter text") },
    modifier = Modifier
        .onFocusChanged { Log.d("TAG", "1 OnFocusChangedCalled: $it") }
)

TextField(
    value = value,
    onValueChange = { value = it },
    label = { Text("Enter text") },
    modifier = Modifier
        .onFocusChanged { Log.d("TAG", "2 OnFocusChangedCalled: $it") }
)
```

Upon simply opening the view, Logcat shows:

```
D/TAG: 1 OnFocusChangedCalled: Inactive
D/TAG: 2 OnFocusChangedCalled: Inactive
```

With traditional XML layouts, onFocusChangedListener only triggers when user actually interacts with the field.

With compose layout, I'm trying to do error validation only when user removes focus from a TextField.

However this behaviour is causing my validation to trigger as soon as the view is initialized.

How can I make the onFocusChanged validation only occur after the user removes focus from the field, instead of upon initialization?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can move the validation in the `onValueChange` attribute instead of the `onFocusChanged` modifier.

As workaround you can store a key when the a field gains the focus and then check this value when the focus is lost.

Something like:

```
 var focusedTextKey by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

 TextField(
    value = value,
    onValueChange = { value = it },
    label = { Text("Enter text") },
    modifier = Modifier
        .onFocusChanged {
            Log.d("TAG", "1 OnFocusChangedCalled: $it")

            if (it.isFocused) {
                focusedTextKey = "NAME"
            } else {
                if (focusedTextKey == "NAME") {
                    //validate the value
                }
                focusedTextKey = ""
            }
        }
    )
```

Comment: Thanks, I've decided to use this workaround for now, but using a boolean instead of a string key. Though it does seem like a bug that onFocusChanged is being called upon creation of the compose TextField.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply make validation happen when you are done with the  field and keyboard action `onNext` is called with the provided validation lambda block you want to execute.

```
OutlinedTextField(
  value = state.email,
  onValueChange = { event(SignupEvent.SetEmail(it)) },
  supportingText={ if(state.isErrorEmail) Text(text = state.errorEmail, maxLines = 1) },
  label={ Text("Email") },
  modifier = Modifier
    .fillMaxWidth(),
  keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(onNext = { event(SignupEvent.CheckEmailValidity) }),
  singleLine = true,
  isError = state.isErrorEmail,
  keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
    // below line is used to specify our
    // type of keyboard such as text, number, phone.
    keyboardType = KeyboardType.Email,
    imeAction = ImeAction.Next
  )
)
```